# "Using Callback Groups" demo is not working

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use MultithreadExecutor in my ROS2 foxy application but it is not working. So I tried the demo code from the guide ["Using callback groups"](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Using-callback-groups.html) to see if it works. Even if I copy everything 1 to 1 I get the error (shown in the guide) as if I use a SingleThreadExecutor or no callback groups.

I am using a Python package with the identical Python code from the demo.
I am using a Docker container with Ubuntu 20.04 and ros-foxy-desktop installed.
(C++ code worked but unfortunately can't program well in it).

Server:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from std_srvs.srv import Empty

class ServiceNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('service_node')
        self.srv = self.create_service(Empty, 'test_service', callback=self.service_callback)

    def service_callback(self, request, result):
        self.get_logger().info('Received request, responding...')
        return result

def main():
    rclpy.init()
    node = ServiceNode()
    try:
        node.get_logger().info("Starting server node, shut down with CTRL-C")
        rclpy.spin(node)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        node.get_logger().info('Keyboard interrupt, shutting down.\n')
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()
```

Client:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.executors import MultiThreadedExecutor
from rclpy.callback_groups import MutuallyExclusiveCallbackGroup, ReentrantCallbackGroup
from rclpy.node import Node
from std_srvs.srv import Empty

class CallbackGroupDemo(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('client_node')

        client_cb_group = MutuallyExclusiveCallbackGroup()
        timer_cb_group = MutuallyExclusiveCallbackGroup()
        self.client = self.create_client(Empty, 'test_service', callback_group=client_cb_group)
        self.call_timer = self.create_timer(1, self._timer_cb, callback_group=timer_cb_group)


    def _timer_cb(self):
        self.get_logger().info('Sending request')
        _ = self.client.call(Empty.Request())
        self.get_logger().info('Received response')


def main():
    rclpy.init()
    node = CallbackGroupDemo()
    executor = MultiThreadedExecutor(num_threads=3)
    executor.add_node(node)

    try:
        node.get_logger().info('Beginning client, shut down with CTRL-C')
        executor.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        node.get_logger().info('Keyboard interrupt, shutting down.\n')
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408276/%22using-callback-groups%22-demo-is-not-working/) by [quirky_franklin](https://answers.ros.org/users/121380/quirky_franklin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-10-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-26**:
I am not sure which guide you are talking about. Therefore, may I request you share the URL of the source code, please?

**Comment by [quirky_franklin](https://answers.ros.org/users/121380/quirky_franklin/) on 2022-10-26**:
Of course here is the link: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Using-callback-groups.html

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-27**:
Your code works fine! Just recompile your workspace, and try again please!

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-10-27**:
Maybe it's a problem with your ROS2 configuration, this tutorial worked for me without problems. As @ravijoshi suggested, remove folders `build`, `log` and `install` from your `ros2_ws` and use `colcon build --symlink install` and `source ~/ros2_ws/install/setub.bash` again.

**Comment by [quirky_franklin](https://answers.ros.org/users/121380/quirky_franklin/) on 2022-10-27**:
Still the same errors:

```
$python3 service.py 
[INFO] [1666868240.642108465] [service_node]: Starting server node, shut down with CTRL-C
[INFO] [1666868284.343087130] [service_node]: Received request, responding...
[INFO] [1666868995.025454979] [service_node]: Keyboard interrupt, shutting down.

$python3 client.py 
Test
[INFO] [1666868283.362897658] [client_node]: Beginning client, shut down with CTRL-C
[INFO] [1666868284.341332508] [client_node]: Sending request
^C[INFO] [1666868997.601692748] [client_node]: Keyboard interrupt, shutting down.
```

**Comment by [oferbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/92002/oferbar/) on 2022-11-21**:
I'm having the same issue. I tried to reproduce the exact code in my ROS workspace (foxy container) without any luck. For some reason, any MultiThreadExecutor example that I tried to reproduce with Python this week seems to fail. By fail, I mean that it act like SingleThreadExecutor. I'm starting to believe that there is a wider problem here.

Edit:

After a few more frustrating hours, I managed to successfully reproduce the demos in Galactic workspace (without container), while the same code wouldn't work in a Foxy container.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-11-22**:
@oferbar: I remember verifying the code. As per my comments, you can noticed that it worked fine. I suspect something wrong with the installation or environment. It could an interesting task to identify it in great details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you very much for the replies. Since it doesn't seem to be ROS, I built a completely new Docker container. 
In the new container it works! 
Now I just need to figure out what is wrong with my main Docker container. But thats another story.

---

Originally posted by [quirky_franklin](https://answers.ros.org/users/121380/quirky_franklin/) with karma: 31 on 2022-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-10-27**:
You should create an issue with this problem on the ROS Github (I think [this one?](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/issues)), especially if the C++ example works in your docker and the Python one isn't.

**Comment by [oferbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/92002/oferbar/) on 2022-11-22**:
For what its worth, I had the exact same problem with my Foxy container. Solved when I worked in a Galactic workspace without container.